# The value of an object inside the controller doesn't change after GET call in AngularJS ??

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, rest, dynamic-arrays

I have average knowledge in AngularJS and can't seem to understand the reason for my problem below:

I have a .service ("SearchMovieService") where I have the GET method defined and it returns a promise.

```
 angular
        .module('module.search-movie')
        .service('SearchMovieService', SearchMovieService);

 SearchMovieService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];
function SearchMovieService($q, $http){
        var movieService = this;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        movieService.getMovies = function(movieName){
            $http.jsonp('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query='+movieName+'&api_key=8484e8613a3235332750c33a23a109b1').then(function(response){
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                    console.log(response)
            });
        return deferred.promise
    }
}
```

In my .controller("SearchMovieController") I have a method that does a GET call using "movieName" as an argument passed from the input field form the view.

```
    var movie = this;
            movie.movies = [];

            movie.searchMovie = function(movieName) {
            if (movieName !== undefined && movieName !== null) {

                SearchMovieService.getMovies(movieName).then(function (response) {
                 movie.movies = response.data.results;
                console.log(movie.movies);
                });
            }
        };
```

And here is my view:

```
       <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="enter a movie name" ng-model="movie.movieName">
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" ng-click="movie.searchMovie(movie.movieName)">
```

**Problem:**
When I enter a movie name in input field and click search, it populates an array of movies in "movie.movies" object. Then when I type a different movie name and click search, the array doesn't change. However, the console.log (response) in Service shows new array, but the console.log(response) in controller still shows the first array.

Can anyone help with this matter? I am using ControllerAs and I have tried $watch, $apply and $digest ... it says they are already in use. Not sure whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the asynchronous call done in the controller. It is very difficult to return an async value from a function and, in my opinion, it would be easier done to perform the call directly inside the controller.

```
if (movieName !== undefined && movieName !== null) {
    $http.jsonp('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query='+movieName+'&api_key=8484e8613a3235332750c33a23a109b1').then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $scope.$apply(function() { // Might need this
             movie.movies = response.data.results;
        })
        console.log(movie.movies); // WILL RETURN NEW ARRAY
    });
    console.log(movie.movies); // WILL RETURN OLD ARRAY
}
```

Your `return` inside the service was returning the old array because the async call had not yet been received. Any `$http` will be async unless specifed otherwise, but I personally would keep is async.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Actually, the service was returning new array at every new call, but the controller was holding on the first call made. But yes, if I do the call in the controller itself, its async and gives expected result. I took a different approach and used a .factory, in the following manner and that solved the problem.